# How to get bundler to show the full command in "ps aux" when running bundle exec?

Tags: ruby, ubuntu, rake, bundler, supervisord

I have a couple of rake tasks that I need to run in background. I'm using `rbenv` to manage my ruby versions, `supervisord` to run the tasks, and `bundle` to make sure I use the correct gems versions. My supervisord config for each task looks like this:

```
[program:data-importer]
command=/home/ubuntu/.rbenv/bin/rbenv exec bundle exec rake import:data
environment=RAILS_ENV=production,PATH=/home/ubuntu/.rbenv/shims:%(ENV_PATH)s,PRODUCTION=true
directory=/home/ubuntu/app/current
user=ubuntu
stdout_logfile=/var/log/app/%(program_name)s-out.log
stderr_logfile=/var/log/app/%(program_name)s-err.log
autostart=true
```

I'm also using `consul` to monitor my infrastructure, and I'm using a consul check to make sure that these scripts are running. The check calls a very simple bash script, shown below:

```
#!/bin/bash

if ps -ef | grep [i]mport:data | grep -v running; then
  echo "data importer running"
  exit 0
else
  echo "data importer not running"
  exit 2
fi
```

These scripts were running just fine until a couple of days ago, when these checks started to fail. The problem is that when I run `ps -ef`, the process listed doesn't contain `import:data` anymore. It now shows this:

```
ubuntu 30450 ... /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/bin/rake
```

Nothing really changed on the machine, only the Ruby version. We used 2.2.2, and we upgraded to 2.3.1 last Friday. That's why I think it's a bundler issue, as we installed a newer version after the ruby upgrade.

We didn't see the problem until Sunday, but it could be that we just didn't see it before.

Can anyone help me with this? I've been stuck for a while now :(

Answer (score 3):

To get the desired output in the ps -ef you have to put quotes around the rake call:

```
bundle exec 'rake import:data'
```